# Empty req.query on ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, express

When I send data from Angular to NodeJS using http.post, it always returns me empty req.query.
My server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query);
    res.send(req.query);
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Successfully');
});
```

Frontend:

```
onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    let data = f.value;
    let httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    };
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:4000/', data, httpOptions).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

And it always returns {} in console. I tried to run POST-requests in POSTMAN and it correctly worked there.
Here is the body of http-request in browser:
[http-request in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDstZ.png)

Hope for your help, thanks.

Comment: What about if you directly append to the URL in the front end as a query string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `req.query` holds the *query string* parameters, looks like you are only passing data up via the body so you want `req.body`

Answer (score 0):

You're using `req.query` but you're sending data in the body, not as query parameters.

Try using `req.body` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You will recive data in body , i.e req.body. Where as for query your api will look like `http://localhost:4000/yourEndPoint?id=XX`